# Spring MVC tunneling requests with HttpClient

Tags: spring-mvc, httpclient, tunnel

I created a Controller to processs all requests to `/tunnel`.

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tunnel/**")
public class TunnelController {

    @RequestMapping
    public void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String url = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length() + "/tunnel".length());

        System.out.println(url);

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        try {
            // inject custom HEADERS
            // tunnel the request and the response to other server
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Then, when I request to http://myserver/my-tunneler/tunnel/resrouce/image.jpg this controller must tunnel internally to http://myotherserver/resource/image.jpg.

How can I tunnel this requests, cloning the request (headers, attributes, parameters, etc), and tunnel to other server using the HttpClient?

Comment: You'd better use a reverse proxy like nginx for this. That's what they're for.

Comment: I need to inject some headers before perform the request like security token and others headers, so i cannot use nginx.